# PHP MySql prepared statements ... How to UPDATE DB, Adding to value already stored

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

So just converting old sql statements into prepared statements

So how do I add to a value already stored in a database?

in old terms I did this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `PT` = PT+$PaymentGross ... ";
```

but how do you accomplish same in prepared statements?

like so:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `PT` = PT+? ...  ";
```

or like so:

```
$stmt->bind_param("i",PT+$PaymentGross ... );
```

couldn't find any info, or perhaps couldn't punch right keywords into google

Comment: So what's the problem with writing the code and test it?

Comment: So what really is your problem? Please provide more detail so that we can help.

Comment: Sorry I tried the statement before it wasn't working. I have just notice that the mistake was elsewhere on the statement line. I assumed I had typed UPDATE `table` SET `PT` = PT+? in wrong. My bad, silly mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way

```
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET `PT`=SUM(`PT`+?) WHERE id=?";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    // This assumes the PT is int `d` and id is int `d`


    $stmt->bind_param('dd', $PaymentGross, $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->errno) {
      echo "FAILURE!!! " . $stmt->error;
    }
    else echo "Updated {$stmt->affected_rows} rows";

    $stmt->close();
```